# Should I reinstall all Python libraries if I install Anaconda's Python as primary in my system?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have been using Python on Windows for some time to analyze survey data, usually available in the form of Excel files. For this reason I have installed several libraries, including pywin32, holoview, bokeh, pandas, numpy and so on.

Now I have found that there is a Python distribution called Anaconda which is a prerequisite for some artificial intelligence libraries that I would like to use.

I downloaded it, but when I install it, it recommends me to register the Python included in Anaconda as primary. This would mean that it would be seen as such by all the tools I use, such as PyCharm.

If I understand correctly, it is possible to have several Python installations on a PC, but what happens to the libraries? I mean, if I make Anaconda's Python primary, do I have to reinstall all the libraries I used before to run the programs I have already written?

I can't find an answer in the Anaconda FAQ, so before proceeding with the installation, I would need to better understand what conflicts I might possibly create on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the some answers from my side.

```
1. Will the libraries & files conflit?
```

> No. - Both local & Anaconda will have separete site packages folders to store installed libraries.No matter how many different versions of python you install there will be separate `site-packages` folders named with respective versions to store `installed libraries`.

```
2. Should I need to re-install packages again that I'm alredy using in older python before I run a program on anaconda?
```

> Yes. **Local python will use** - cmd -WIndows command prompot
> **Anoconda will use** - Anaconda prompt - Which will be installed along with installation. Both `Anconda` and local `python` maintains separate storage locations in order to store & process data which includes libraries, settings, Environments, cache....

```
3.if we selects Anaconda as primary. This would mean that it would be seen as such by all the tools I use, such as PyCharm?
```

> No. Pycharm will have old configuartion whatever you using currently
> even thouh we install anaconda & make its a primary. But, still you
> can use anaconda from pycharm by creating a virtual environmnet for it.